# SVG not displaying at all on some versions of Firefox

Tags: firefox, svg, cross-browser

I recently had problems with displaying SVG files in Firefox, but I overcame that by explicitly stating the width and height in the .svg file source. That fixed the problem for me on my Firefox, but some users still report problems on some versions. Are you able to reproduce the problem? What might be the solution? This is the website: http://naratifrevue.cz – it's using a glitch script on SVG images in the header.

Comment: No ideas anyone? Can't seem to figure it out,